# Work-from-home FAQ for Oracle app running in Citrix

Tags: oracle, performance, browser, citrix

I am a retired engineer, my spouse is still working, 100% from home.
My spouse is running an Oracle-based tool that reports budget info, in a Citrix environment.
Spouse is frustrated by lag time and unresponsive desktop. I can't figure out how the pieces fit together, can't offer any help.

Spouses employer appears to not have a FAQ  or Step By Step Guide for the Complete Idiot to follow. I don't want to endanger our marriage but I'd love to be more helpful. Haven't found the right way to ask questions I can learn anything from. Spouse has a path that leads successfully through the jungle. Oral tradition? Effectively. Stress levels are high, my asking questions, or seeming impatient, costs more than any benefit that might come from it.

Spouse's co-workers report they use Firefox or Safari with Citrix, apparently, not Chrome. Not clear where a web browser fits- presumably the Oracle based tool is installed in the Citrix app layer? Or would a Citrix virtual desktop then need a web browser to host web-based user interface (ie "thin client") for a remote server? Budget reporting system has hundreds of users, many millions of dollars.

20 years ago I used Citrix to access Windows apps while working in a SunOS engineering environment.  Is there any way I can learn enough to make sense of my spouse's experiences?

Comment: You're a good spouse! But sorry, StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems.  Your Q **may be**  more appropriate for [su]  , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck!

Comment: My spouse worked in a similar environment, (in that her on-line access would freeze, crash, stall, you name it).  Do a `tracert` to the IP of the offending system, and if there are long delays in the path, then "you" have a network problem. If the whole path executes quickly, then "they" have a server/network/etc problem. We would raise tickets, (when it was a crisis) and sometimes we'd get thru to a person that could help, but probably less than 1/2 the time. Have your spouse see if others are having the same problems VS others that aren't. Giving the support team this info might help.GdLuck!

Comment: Thank you shellter. https://stackoverflow.com/users/620097/shellter. I'll try "tracert" today. I looked at Citrix's support area and didn't find anything like a block diagram for a typical, or canonical, Citrix Workspace. I did look for answers my question or mentions of Citrix within  "Stack Exchange", "Stack Overflow" was where I found it discussed. Either here or on their support site, Citrix not working with Chrome, or vice-versa, was mentioned. I'll go look at Super User again.

Comment: Yes, it's very confusing, and it has changed over time where is the appropriate place to post a Q. So with all the "history" in the internet search engines, S.O. gets a lot of Qs that are technically off topic. Incidentally, do `tracert 9.9.9.9` to get a baseline for how networking information comes back to you. Just did it, and while it reported 10ms or less or each hop, there where multiple second delays between each step of output. Frankly, I'm surprized that Chrome iis causing trouble for anybody. (That's about all I know on this topic that can help (not much ;-/) ). Good luck!